# Double refraction

Tags: optics, refraction

What is the mathematical relation for velocity of extraordinary ray ( e-ray) with refractive index of medium and the angle of incidence with optic axis in a Uniaxial mineral, Such as calcite?

Comment: Velocity of light is  $\frac{c}{n}$ so whatever index value applies to your material &  polarization is all that matters.  Can you clarify what you're actually trying to calculate?

Comment: See also: birefringence

Comment: The demand of the question is that in case of double refraction o-ray and e-ray have different velocities in a direction other than optic axis. In this case o-ray follow snell's law but e-ray not. So what is the mathematical equations which can be used to calculate velocity of e-ray in medium. (Particularly Calcite crystal).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually somewhat complicated to work through and the somewhat tedious algebra depends on the details of the type of crystal. One reference that goes through the derivation is.

Quan-Ting Liang, "Simple ray tracing formulas for uniaxial optical crystals," Appl. Opt. 29, 1008-1010 (1990)

But there are several other Applied Optics paper that go into the subject in detail.